# New Plugin Info request

Tags: plugins, support

I want to upload my new plug in and before that, I have a few questions I did not find an answer yet.

1. Is there a set up fee for plugin from wordpress? Is the approval and listing procedure for free?
2. Is there an exit fee? In case I want to remove my plugin from wordpress, will there be a fee?
3. What kind of support will I be faced to? I mean, I know that I will be posting updates and fix any bugs that arise from that, but are there any other issues that I cannot think of?

And finally, where do I get the information regarding pricing and fees for wordpress? I am looking for a complete guide for pricing and fees and taxes. I did not find any info on wordpress site.

Thanks. Looking forward for you help.

Comment: It depends on where you're submitting it. You should ask them.

Comment: If you mean the wordpress.org public plugin directory then there's nothing about fees in [the FAQ](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/), so I'd guess there aren't any. There's an email address on that page though if you want to ask them any questions directly.

Comment: Hi Kiriaki. Please can you add information to your question about what websites or services you're talking about? Wordpress itself is open source software, but there are organisations such as wordpress.com which sell services around the Wordpress software - we need to know which ones specifically you're talking about